# Selecting the Optimal Attribute Value from Duplicate Pairs in a Pandas DataFrame using Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-wrangling

I'm trying to clean a list of data by de-duplicating data. I extracted all the duplicates from a primary key, created a soundex+DOB blocking key variable and found that there are exactly 2 duplicates for each set (so found all matches).

Now, I am trying to clean the data by choosing the most appropriate attribute between each duplicate pair.

I am not the best at python code so I would like to get some general direction on how I create the loops between each attribute.

Below is the dataframe with the column names

```
Index(['rec_id', 'ssn', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'gender',
       'current_age', 'birth_date', 'street_address', 'suburb', 'postcode',
       'state', 'phone', 'email', 'education', 'occupation', 'salary',
       'credit_card_number', 'years_of_experience', 'employment_timestamp',
       'sd_fn', 'DOB_df', 'BKV_1'],
      dtype='object')
```

My rules for choosing best attribute are:

| Column | Rule |
| --- | --- |
| first_name | use most recent_timestamp |
| middle_name | keep longest name |
| last_name | use most recent_timestamp |
| gender | use most recent_timestamp |
| current_age | use most recent_timestamp |
| birt_date | use most recent_timestamp |
| address | use most recent_timestamp |
| phone | use most recent_timestamp |
| email | check if valid, then use most recent_timestamp |
| education | use most recent_timestamp |
| occupation | use most recent_timestamp |
| salary | use most recent_timestamp |
| ccn | use most recent_timestamp |
| years_experience | use most recent_timestamp |

Note: I have only been using python for two weeks and I am not a coder (mechanical engineer) - so please go easy!

I extracted the data into a separate data frame and now need to choose the most appropriate attribute of the pair.

Comment: Please make your example minimal. Instead of 10+ columns, pick 3/4 representative example and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464) of the data with the matching expected output.